# Japanese idiom « J'aimerais même qu’un chat me prête main-forte »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

I just sent this message to a French speaker:

> Je suis tellement débordé ces temps-ci que « **j'aimerais même qu’un chat me prête main-forte** » ! Peut-être bien que ça t'échappe, cette expression, mais on l’emploie quand on est extrêmement occupé.
>
> En parlant du chat, les francophones utilisent « appeler un chat un chat », expression que je trouve intéressante. On dit, en revanche, « tenir des propos sans habiller les dents » pour signifier « parler franchement ».

---

In Japanese, we say "猫の手も借りたい" that literally means "(I’m so busy that) I even wish a cat lent me a hand/paw".

« Prêter main-forte » happens to conveniently express the idea of both "a help" and "a hand/paw". But I wonder if there is a better phrasing to get this Japanese expression across to French speakers.

Comment: Y a-t-il ironie à l'effet que la patte du chat est franchement inutile en contexte vu sa délicatesse par rapport à une épreuve particulièrement rude, ou c'est l'idée de n'importe quoi de plus ? La partie en parenthèse _I'm so busy that_ fait-elle partie de l'expression, ou pourrait-elle être remplacée par n'importe quel état/situation ? Merci.

Comment: @Ange-à-Liberté Hi. La partie entre parenthèses (I’m so busy that), il ne s’agit que d’un contexte dans lequel uniquement on emploie cette expression. C'est-à-dire, lorsque l’on est désespérément débordé. Au point d'ailleurs de se rabaisser à compter sur un chat pour nous porter secours, aussi irréaliste soit-il.

Comment: It wouldn’t have the cute reference to cats & their paws, but if you don’t mind something that simply captures the original idiom’s figurative meaning (as I see it) of “being [so very] busy,” you could consider looking for a good French equivalent (literal or not) of “There just aren’t enough hours in the day [to get it all done].”  (also, [here’s a thread about “cat” expressions in French & Japanese](http://www.lejapon.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-6941.html) and near the bottom *konaritai* translates the idiom at issue as “je suis tellement débordé que j'accepterai même l'aide d'un chat.”)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Prêter main-forte* is slightly outdated and/or formal.

I would suggest:

> Je ne dirais pas non si un chat proposait de me donner un coup de main !

Comment: Or: _je ne dirais pas non si un chat proposait de me donner un coup de main!_ in order to avoid the repetition of _me_.

Comment: @Frank Oui, c'est mieux. Merci.

Comment: @jiliagre I wouldn't say that *prêter main-forte* is outdated. It's just less informal than *donner un coup de main*.

Comment: Le _je ne dirais pas non_ ne colle pas très bien à l'original (ps: je n'ai _pas_ downvoté et je ne vois pas pourquoi cette réponse a été downvotée).

Comment: @Frank Je n'ai aucune idée de ce que dit précisément l'original, ne connaissant rien, contrairement à vous, au japonais. Je me suis donc appuyé sur la traduction anglaise proposée puis ai choisi l'expression qui me semble le mieux rendre en français l'idée de ce que j'en ai compris. Le fait qu'une traduction ne colle pas très bien à l'original n'est pas nécessairement un problème si l'idée transmise est préservée.

Comment: Je suis d'accord - et j'ai tendance à traduire de façon libérale. C'était juste un commentaire en passant, et je pense que votre traduction est tout à fait acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Nous n'avons pas la même culture en France le "gambate" n'existe pas vraiment. Ainsi les expressions sur le "débordement" travail / vie personnelle ne sont pas légion (une autre expression :p) il faut savoir que la main forte dans son sens original, était liée à la justice mais pas pour le sentiment de ne plus savoir quoi faire parce que trop de choses à faire.

A mon humble avis, je pense les expressions qui se rapprochent de ce que vous dites chez nous sont plus négatives tel que par exemple "au bout du rouleau" (c'est la fin), "je ne sais pas par quel bout commencer" (quand au début d'un travail, celui-ci semble gigantesque)

Vouloir traduire une expression d'une langue avec sa culture vers une autre qui a une autre culture est 難しい.

Comment: Non seulement 難しいmais même parfois impossible, surtout pour ce qui est d'une langue aussi différente du français que le japonais. Pour l'anglais, l'allemand, l'espagnol..., les références sont grosso modo encore partagées (avec déjà des différences notables), mais pour le japonais, il n'y a parfois pas de référence commune. Les réactions, les attitudes et le langage qui leur est lié (je ne sais pas si le langage est premier ou second), peuvent être suffisamment différents qu'ils ne sont pas "compréhensibles" sans explications.

Answer (score 1):

I would have rendered「猫の手も借りたい」as

> *j'accepterais même l'aide d'un chat*

or

> *je demanderais même à un chat de m'aider*

or

> *même l'aide d'un (simple) chat me serait utile/serait la bienvenue*

or

> *j'aurais presque envie de demander de l'aide à un chat*
>
> *je suis sur le point de demander à un chat de me donner un coup de main*

(the last two ones probably convey「ーたい」better)

since in the idiom「手を借りる」the idea of *hand* "disappears" in favor of the meaning of *to help*. Of course, you can try to maintain it (it's there after all) and look for a French equivalent with *main*. But saying that you would *welcome the help (even) from a cat* might be "idiomatic" enough in itself already.

Comment: *Prendre l'aide* seems an anglicism and that's *l'aide **d**'un chat*.

Comment: J'ai corrigé, merci.